# Texture on a mesh doesn't render correctly Libgdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, shader, mesh

I am trying to put a texture on a mesh, but failing. 
I am trying to render [something like this, where texture can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9GFx.jpg) but I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1IAZ.jpg), where I can barely see the triangle. I am running the following code:

```
public class Game implements ApplicationListener{

Mesh mesh;
ShaderProgram shader;
Texture texture;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LwjglApplication app = new LwjglApplication(new Game(), "Mesh Tutorial 1", 800, 600, true);
}

protected static ShaderProgram createMeshShader() {

    String vert = Gdx.files.internal("data/VertexShader.txt").readString();
    String frag = Gdx.files.internal("data/FragmentShader.txt").readString();

    ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
    ShaderProgram shader = new ShaderProgram(vert, frag);
    return shader;
}

@Override
public void create() {


    if (mesh == null) {
        mesh = new Mesh(true, 3, 3, 
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE),
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.Color, 4, ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE),
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE));

       mesh.setVertices(new float[] { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f, 1f, 0, 1,
                                       0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.1f, 1f, 1, 1,
                                       0, 0.5f, 0, 0, 0.4f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f, 0 });

        mesh.setIndices(new short[] { 0, 1, 2 });

        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/badlogic.png"));
    }
    shader = createMeshShader();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    texture.bind();
    mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {}
@Override
public void pause() {}
@Override
public void resume() {}
@Override
public void dispose() {}
```

The **Vertexshader** is:

```
attribute vec4 a_position; 
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoords;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
void main() {
    vColor = a_color;
    vTexCoord = a_texCoords;
    gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

**Fragmentshader**:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main(){
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    gl_FragColor = v_color * texColor;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but aren't you missing the part where you set your uniforms?

See the following as an example: [OpenGlShader](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Shaders#a-simple-shaderprogram)